# KineticJS make text vertically aligned

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am trying to draw something with KineticJS. I want to make text vertically aligned, but have not find an attribute to make it rendered like I want.

I tried "align", "verticalAlign" but none of these satisfy my requirements.

I want the text show like this:

```
T
E
X
T
```

But it doesn't work and always displays like this:

```
TEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best bet would be to create the text separetly and adding it to a group, maybe a function like:

```
function(text){
   group = new Kinetic.Group();
   letters=text.split("");
   for(foo in letters){
    window['text' + foo] = new Kinetic.Text({config}) // use the foo incrementaly to change the Y axis of the text and pass letters[foo] as text argument
    group.add(window['text' + foo]);


   }
   layer.add(group);
   layer.draw();
}
```

It can be written more elegantly (not using the window object, but thats the only way i know to create dinamic vars) but that should get the work done (I think);